# R tweets for specific dates - issue

Tags: r, date, twitter

I'm trying to get Tweets in R for specific date ranges. From what I've read, the following R code should work, but I get no results:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

searchTwitter('green', since='2013-03-01', until='2013-03-31',cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

However, this code does work, i.e. with a date range of the last few days.

```
searchTwitter('green', since='2013-06-01', until='2013-06-15', cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

Is it that we can only go back several days of tweets? Not months? How far back can we go?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API will only let you go back a few days