# twitteR package date range issue in R

Tags: r, twitter

So I am trying to find tweets based on date range with this code:

```
  tweets <- searchTwitter(c("Alzheimer"), n=500, lang="en", 
            since="2011-03-01", until="2011-03-02")
```

and I get the warning message

> In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit
>   =   retryOnRateLimit,  :
>       500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0

BUT I don't get this warning message with the code

```
 tweets <- searchTwitter(c("Alzheimer"), n=500, lang="en", since="2011-08-01")
```

I've read many posts previously about twitter not allowing a date range past a few days...is this still the case currently?? I'm new to coding so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120050/r-tweets-for-specific-dates-issue. The twitter API does not allow historic queries. They only index a few days worth of tweets.

Answer (score 0):

MrFlick is right in his comment, the twitter API only returns tweets for the past few days, as to why you are not getting the warning on the second command, my guess is because its working.  I tried this command from my terminal and got back 500 tweets.